# .NET Windows Forms Datagridview mousedown event not firing

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, mouseevent, visual-studio-debugging

I have an application written in VS.NET Visual Basic on Visual Studio 2005.

It has a Windows form, with a `DataGridView` control on it to display data retrieved from a database.

I want to allow the user to right-click on a record, see a context menu and be able to click delete to delete just that record from the database.

Unfortunately I can't even get the mouse down or click events to fire (in debug mode, with breakpoints set)

here is my code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    MessageBox.Show("You right-clicked on the grid at", "Unpaid", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDoubleClick
    MessageBox.Show("You right-clicked on the grid at", "Unpaid", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDown

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked right")
    else 
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked left")
    End If

    Dim r As Rectangle
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True
        r = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, True)
        contextMnu.Show(DataGridView1, r.Left + e.X, r.Top + e.Y)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteChequeToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DeleteChequeToolStripMenuItem.Click
    MessageBox.Show("You right-clicked on the grid", "Unpaid", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End Sub
```

As you can see, I am trying to get some event, any event to fire, and none of code is running when I right-click or even left -click.

BTW, there is data in the grid at run time, and as far as I am aware, it is enabled

So what am I doing wrong here? Is there some feature I need to add to the `DataGridView` control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing with your code and the CellMouseDown works when clicking in a cell somewhere in a populated datagridview. I populated the data manually during the design time.  I haven't tried this during the run time mode.

You can get the empty DataGridView1 to fire events MouseDown() and DoubleClick() though even if it's not populated. However, this by itself doesn't know what cells you are clicking.  Also, The MouseDown would take precedent over the DoubleClick and you won't see double click here.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles     DataGridView1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then

        MessageBox.Show("Clicked right")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked left")
    End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub DataGridView1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DoubleClick
    MessageBox.Show("Double Clicked")
 End Sub
```

[EDIT 2/25/2013]

I tried to dynamically add data to the datagridview using the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim testData As New List(Of String)
    testData.Add("1")
    testData.Add("2")
    testData.Add("3")
    Dim dataBindingSource As New BindingSource
    dataBindingSource.DataSource = testData
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dataBindingSource
End Sub
```

I still can fire the DataGridView1_CellMouseDown events.   Perhaps you could try an empty project with just the datagridview and try it out to see where your problem might have occurred?

Comment: could my debug issues be related to the forms parent (MDI Form called MDI Child) ?

Comment: Ahh, you should have mentioned that in the first plate. I noticed having the same problem if the "Handles <Event>" is not where the event call is.  I suggest removing all the events you have and try adding the event cellmousedown from the Child form GUI event adder.  Then type "Handles" after the event to see the choices that intellisense brings up.  I chose DataGridView1.CellMouseDown.  Then the event seems to fire normally.

Comment: Also, are you setting the child form to use the main form as the parent?  Something like this in the parent form: 
FormChild.MdiParent = Me

Comment: I don't think that's the problem:
Here below is how the child form is loaded on the menu click event in the MDI Parent:

        Dim NewMDIChild As New frmReportsEquationSubmissions
        If bUnpaidIn_InputLoaded = False Then
            'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
            NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me
            NewMDIChild.ProcessDateToLook = 1
            'Display the new form.
            NewMDIChild.Show()
        End If

I tried removing all the event handlers, and added one and it seems to be ok (see next comment)

Comment: Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDown

Comment: After you removed all the events, now it's working with the CellMouseDown event ?

Comment: no what I meant was that the Handles ... was correct (DataGridView1.CellMouseDown) but no event is being fired with the breakpoint

Comment: another question - what's the difference in VS.NET Solution Explorer between 'frmEquationSubmissionDay1.vb' and it's child 'frmEquationSubmissionDay1.Designer.vb' ?

Comment: very sorry about my dumbness (total beginner on VS, coming from VB6), I am now wondering whether I have actually been running my changed code...When I click Run (Debug) do I have to do a complete build first with no errors?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25176/discussion-between-patratacus-and-philip)

Answer (score 0):

very sorry about my dumbness (total beginner on VS, coming from VB6).

It turns out that the VB Project settings had Build only on Compile for release set to True, so even though I thought I was running my changed code, I wasn't!

So after I changed that, and ran Project...Clean followed by Project... Build my events started working.

Thanks anyway!
Philip